# Left eigenvectors of a complex nonsymmetric matrix and the diagonalization transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable complex nonsymmetric matrix. Let $D=S^{-1}AS$ be a diagonalization of $A$, so $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
The columns of $S$ are (right) eigenvectors of $A$. What is the relationship between left eigenvectors of $A$ and $S^{-1}$?

Comment: This is confusing. If $A$ is not supposed symmetric (or Hermitian, or normal) there is no reason that $S$ could be taken to be unitary. (In fact it cannot if $A$ is no normal.)

Comment: Also you don't need to (indeed are not supposed to) Captalise All Words In The Title.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Unitarity is an edit by William, not in the original question.

Comment: OK, so I rolled back to (almost) the original question.

Comment: A note for anyone computing $S^{-1}$ with [Matlab](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#btwn8vj-1) or [Lapack](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/469230): the definition of the left eigenvector adopted there uses a conjugate of the vector defined in the two answers below. Therefore, the left eigenvectors computed by these libraries are the conjugates of the rows of $S^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rows of $S^{-1}$ are the left eigenvectors of $A$:

Assuming $A,D,S\in\mathbb C^n$ with $D=S^{-1}AS$ and $D$ is diagonal. By multiplying with $S^{-1}$ from the right, we get
\begin{align}
DS^{-1} = S^{-1}A.\tag{1}
\end{align}

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb C^n$ be the row vectors such that of $S^{-1}$
$$
S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\\vdots\\v_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
which makes $v_i$ the $i$th row of $S^{-1}$.

Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb C$ be the diagonal elements of $D$. (This makes them the Eigenvalues including muliplicities of $A$.) This means that we have
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & \\
          & \lambda_2 \\
          &            & \ddots \\
          &            &        & \lambda_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now we can write (1) in the following form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1v_1\\\vdots\\\lambda_nv_n\end{bmatrix} 
= D S^{-1} = S^{-1} A = \begin{bmatrix}v_1A\\\vdots\\v_nA\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Note that $v_iA\in\mathbb C^n$ is well defined row vector for all $i$.
By taking the $i$th row of the above equation we get
$$
\lambda_i v_i = v_i A,
$$
where $v_i$ is the $i$th row of $S^{-1}$ and $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th Eigenvalue. This makes the rows of $S^{-1}$ the left Eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: This is assuming that $A$ is normal, whereas not all diagonalizable matrices are normal.

Comment: @William Why?  S/he just multiplied $D=S^{-1}AS$ on the right by $S^{-1}$ and took the $i^\text{th}$ row of both sides.  ( I think there's a typo column->row in the second sentence ).

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo.

Comment: There appear to be a lot of steps missing, so I don't quite see the argument, but we can't assume that the rows of $S^{-1}$ are orthonormal unless $S$ is unitary, i.e. unless $A$ is normal.

Comment: @William There's exactly two steps.  Multiply both sides of the equation on the right by $S^{-1}$.  Look at $i^\text{th}$ row.

Comment: Steps are hidden in the process of deducing the structure of the $i$th row

Comment: It should be the ith column of $(S^{-1})^*$ not the ith row of $S^{-1}$. The only way the answer can be correct is if one assumes that $S$ is unitary.

Comment: @William okay.  To get the $i^\text{th}$ row of a matrix product $MN$ we look at the product of the $i^\text{th}$ row of $M$ times $N$.   For $S^{-1}$, the $i^{th}$ row is $v^T$, so the $i^\text{th}$ row of $S^{-1}A$ is $v^TA$.  For $D$, the $i^\text{th}$ row is all zeros with $\lambda$ as the $i^\text{th}$ entry, so the $j^\text{th}$ entry in the $i^\text{th}$ row of $DS^{-1}$ is $\lambda$ times the $j^\text{th}$ entry of $i^\text{th}$ row of $S^{-1}$, so it's $\lambda \cdot v^T$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization

Comment: @Callus I seem to be missing something, but I thought that the $i$th row of $S^{-1}$ is $v^T$ only if $S$ is (real) orthogonal, and $v^*$ only if $S$ is unitary. So the assumption does seem to be that $S$ is unitary, which is not true in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40680/discussion-between-callus-and-william).

Comment: I increased the verbosity of my answer. The matter should be crystal clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume first that $A$ is normal, i.e. that it can be diagonalized by unitary matrices (as a consequence of the spectral theorem).

Since $S$ is unitary, its inverse $S^{-1}$ is its conjugate transpose.

We know that the left eigenvectors of $A$ are the conjugate transpose of the right eigenvectors of $A$.

Since the right eigenvectors of $A$ are the columns of $S$, it follows that the left eigenvectors of $A$ are the rows of the conjugate transpose of $S$.

But as was mentioned at the outset, the conjugate transpose of $S$ is just $S^{-1}$ (since $S$ is unitary).

Therefore, the left eigenvectors of $A$ are the rows of $S^{-1}$.

Another way to think of this is that $$(S^{-1} A S)^* = S^* A^* (S^{-1})^* = S^{-1} A^* S$$ is the diagonalization of the conjugate transpose of $A$, and we know that a vector is a left eigenvector for $A$ if and only if its conjugate is a right eigenvector for the conjugate transpose of $A$, namely $A^*$.

See for example [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme335/lecture4sup.pdf) for more detail.

---

Now consider the case where $A$ is diagonalizable but not normal (examples exist, see [enter link description here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiagonalizableMatrix.html)). Then we have: $$D = S^{-1} A S$$ for $S$ NOT unitary.

It still holds that $y$ is a left eigenvector of $A$ if and only if it is the conjugate of a right eigenvector for $A^*$: $$y^T A = \lambda y^T \iff A^* \bar{y} = \bar{\lambda} \bar{y}$$

So let us examine the diagonalization of $A^*$: $$(S^{-1} A S)^* = S^* A^* (S^{-1})^*$$

Note that all of the steps are the same here except that we cannot simplify at the end, since $S$ is *not* unitary.

If $w$ is a right eigenvector of $A^*$, then it is a column of $(S^{-1})^*$. Therefore $\bar{w}$ is a left eigenvector of $A$.

Hence $y$ is a left eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $\bar{y}$ is a column of $(S^{-1})^*$.

Comment: I think $D^* = S^*A^*(S^{-1})^*$ is the diagonalization of the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Comment: Isn't $S$ unitary only when $A$ is Hermitian?

Comment: No, $S$ is unitary if and only if $A$ is normal (spectral theorem -- see chapter 7 of Axler, Linear Algebra done right, for example), and there are plenty of normal matrices which are not unitary. Since my post assumed that $A$ is normal, I added a section which considers the case when $A$ is diagonalizable but not normal.

Comment: I took a simple matrix to Matlab `A=[1+i,2-i,3;1,i,0.5i;5i,7,-2]`, diagonalized it, but haven't seen any relation between $S^{-1}$ and the left eigenvectors computed by Matlab.

Comment: you normalized the eigenvectors first, correct? and does Matlab have a routine specific for left eigenvectors, or did you compute them from the right eigenvectors? and you took the conjugate transpose, not the regular transpose, correct?

Comment: Yes, Matlab computes both right and left eigenvectors normalized to unity. By the way, in your definition of the left eigenvector I think it should be $y^{*}$ not $y^{T}$

Comment: No the $y^T$ only expresses the fact that we are dealing with a row vector, not a column vector -- if we want to discuss the properties of $y$ and not its conjugate, it makes no sense to define $y$ as being a left eigenvector contingent on the behavior of $y^*$.

Comment: To tie your conclusion to the other answer, if $\bar{y}$ is a column of $(S^{-1})^{*}$, then $y$ is a row of $S^{-1}$, so it's true even if $A$ is not normal.

Comment: Also the eigenvectors on one side are not forcedly orthogonal and the scalar product $$x_L^i\cdot x_R^i$$ is 1 but theycan be not colinear but not normalized to 1 (using euclidean metric)